# Can anyone explain how Release Management compliments TFS in the devOps pipeline?

Tags: tfs, release-management, alm

I always get confused which area they both cover in the DevOps space from a Microsoft perspective. Understanding ALM and what are roles does each play? How do they provide solution consolidation for multiple projects/teams for code deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Team Foundation Server (TFS) is a product that provides ***source code management*** (either TFVC or Git), **reporting**, **requirements management**, **project management** (such as agile software development), **automated builds**, **lab management**, **testing** and **release management capabilities.**

> **TFS covers the entire application lifecycle**, and enables DevOps capabilities.

So in short, relase mangement is just a part of TFS. Release Management features **have been integrated into** *Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 Update 2 and above*, and into **the Release hub in TFS web access**.

[image]